# Set a base class 'let' variable in child class with swift

Tags: inheritance, swift, sprite-kit

I have a base class that inherits SKScene:

```
class BaseClass: SKScene {
    let round: Int!
}
```

And a class that inherits the base class :

```
class ChildClass: BaseClass {
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size)
        self.round = 1
    }
}
```

Somehow, I can't modify `self.round`. It says `Cannot assign to 'round' in 'self'`.

I thought the exclamation mark would let me set the value later.

Comment: let bindings imply immutability.  `!` isn't for mutability, it's for implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties declared with `let` are only mutable in an initializer of the class they belong to. If you need a subclass to change the value, your options are (1) to change `round` to a `var` declaration or (2) to create an initializer in `BaseClass` that accepts a value for `round`.

The first is trivial; here's an example of the second:

```
class BaseClass: SKScene {
    let round: Int!

    init(size: CGSize, round: Int) {
        self.round = round
        super.init(size: size)
    }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size, round: 1)
    }
}
```

(Leaving out the `init(coder:)` implementations...)

Comment: Too bad, there is no trickless way to use let :/ Thank you Nate Cook !